# jQuery multiselect filter widget - filter text box focus issue

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using jQuery multiselect filter widget (http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) in a dojo dialog box. I see the strange behavior for filter input field related to focus. I am not able to click on filter input field, focus moves to first element on form (dojo dialog box has few form elements) when I click on filter to enter filter text. This works perfectly when used independently in a normal html page.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code here

Answer (score 0):

When you create your multi select widget simply add the following "open" method.

```
$("#MyStatusWidget").multiselect({
open: function () {
    $("input[type='search']:first").focus();                   
}
});
```